# How do I know I divide dataset into training set, validation set and test set in a correct/appropriate proportion?

Tags: machine-learning, validation

Chapter 3 of [Tom M. Mitchell. Machine Learning (free)](http://profsite.um.ac.ir/~monsefi/machine-learning/pdf/Machine-Learning-Tom-Mitchell.pdf) gives this advice:

> One common heuristic is to withhold one-third of the available examples for the
>   validation set, using the other two-thirds for training.

**Note:** the part cited above does not involve test set.

Page 70 of that books says

> the available data has been split into three subsets: the
>   training examples, the validation examples used for pruning the tree, and a set of
>   test examples used to provide an unbiased estimate of accuracy over future unseen
>   examples.

**Note:** the part cited above does not give specific number like one-third, two-thirds.

In practice, such as iris dataset, mnist dataset, titanic dataset, ImageNet dataset, when do I need to divide dataset into training set, validation set and test set? How to do that? How do I know I divide dataset into training set, validation set and test set in a correct/appropriate proportion?

for example, there are 70000 examples in mnist, It can be split in a training set of the first 60,000 examples, and a test set of 10,000 examples. this dividing does involve the validation set, why?

Comment: imagenet and mnist have standardized splits

Comment: @shimao for example, there are 70000 examples in mnist, It can be split in a training set of the first 60,000 examples, and a test set of 10,000 examples. this dividing does involve the validation set, why?